# SSRS 2016 Connection String for Non-Local Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, connection-string, sql-server-2016

I am trying to connect to a server that is not locally stored on my reporting server.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx

I am trying to use: Data Source=localhost\MSSQL13.; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks

However, my data source is not on the localhost. What is the correct path I need to be using for my server to connect? I have the instance path, but it is in a localized format. (EX. D:\MSSQLSERVER...)

Comment: You need to change the data source to point to the server hosting your SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the name of the remote SQL Server as the `Data Source` in your connection string.

Comment: Do I need <> characters? Like: <Data Source>?

Comment: No.  Just the name of the server instead of `localhost\MSSQL13`

Comment: Gotcha. That is what I have been attempting. It's still not connecting though. I think it is a permissions issue.